# Is it possible to detect JBoss/WildFly PID?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

When running in Domain mode, there are several JBoss JVMs running. Is it possible to detect which is the PID related to one server instance ? I need to monitor a specific server through JConsole, but I'm not able to figure out which one is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a scenario here to try, so, could you give **jps** a try?

```
jps -lv
```

From the **jps** *man page*:

- -l  Displays the full package name for the application's main class or the full path name to the application's JAR file.
- -v  Displays the arguments passed to the JVM.

Maybe the arguments passed to the JVM have a hint.

Comment: There should be an argument like `-D[Server:server-name]` passed in the argument that the `-v` argument will print.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of domain installation, just check the file below.

In the installation directory /domain/wildfly.pid shows the PID that is running

In the case of standalone, the file should be /standalone/wildfly.pid